# Map tables relationship w/ only primary keys from existing database to entity framework objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have the following tables in a legacy database.

**data**
dataid PK,
year,
number

**data_1**
dataid PK,
note_1,
completed

**data_2**
dataid PK,
note_2,
type,
object

**data_other**
dataid PK,
note_other,
a,
b,
c

My model classes looks like;

```
public class Data
{
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int Note1{ get; set; }
    public int Completed { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int Note2 { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Object { get; set; }
}

public class DataOther
{
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int NoteOther { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

```C#
    public DbSet<Data> Datas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Data1> Data1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Data2> Data2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DataOther> DataOthers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().ToTable("data");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().HasKey(t => t.DataID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Data1>().ToTable("data_1");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Data1>().HasKey(t => t.DataID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Data2>().ToTable("data_2");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Data2>().HasKey(t => t.DataID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DataOther>().ToTable("data_other");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataOther>().HasKey(t => t.DataID);
    }
```

I have tried different solutions from tutorials and blogs but I cant seem to make it happen,

```C#
modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
    .HasRequired(a => a)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a);
```

The problem as I see it is that we only have Primary keys and no Foreign keys. Im using MVC3 and Entity Framework 5. What I want is to only go thrue for example in the view @Model.Datas.Others.NoteOther

But any tips on how I can create relationships between these tables are great!

Comment: Is there some reason you're not generating the model from the database?

Comment: If you do Database-First, you can add associations to your model - you just have to be careful, that the association uses your own fields and does not create new ones. I use it that way and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, its because there are other legacy systems using the database. I am trying to add a search functionally.

Comment: @Grumbler85 So it should work to do mappings anyway? Would be much appreciated if you provided me with an example.

Comment: I don't do code-first, so i cannot, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want several 1:0..1 relationships.

To map this, first you need to map the actual relationships in your class:

```
public class Data
{
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Data1 Data1 { get; set; }
    public Data2 Data2 { get; set; }
    public DataOther DataOther { get; set; }
}
```

And then, define the relationship using fluent:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().HasOptional(d => d.Data1)
            .WithRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().HasOptional(d => d.Data2)
            .WithRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().HasOptional(d => d.DataOther)
            .WithRequired();
```

This produced this Database for me:

[image]

Comment: It feels like Im almost there. But every time I try Model.Datas.Others.NoteOther Others is NULL. Suppose its truly is a 1-1 mapping how do I do that, cant seem to work that out!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question - Is there a Data_Other item in the for your Data object?  If so, you may need to eager load using [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).  If you're wanting to create a new one, you can Just create a new DataOther and attach it - EF will work out the PK's.  Or are you saying this is 1:1 not 1:0..1?  If so, we'll need to update the fluent a bit.

Comment: That solved my problem, had to use include in my querys to turn on eager loading!

Comment: Happy to help!  I see that you're new - don't forget to mark this as an answer for future visitors.  You may also want to check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how the community works!